# NullPointerException when opening Debug Configurations on the project MyEclipse

Tags: debugging, tomcat, plugins, configuration, myeclipse

Good day,

It started as I couldn't start the Tomcat in debug mode - it hangs at this point:

[image]

So after I started it not in debug mode and started fine.

Tried to see the Debug Configurations and got this `NullPinterException`

Project -> Debug As -> Debug Configurations produces the following error:

[image]

**The log:**

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.jface 4 2 2016-03-07 10:13:42.937
!MESSAGE Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.jface".
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.genuitec.eclipse.server.ui.launching.ServerLaunchConfigurationTab.getServerConnectors(ServerLaunchConfigurationTab.java:95)
    at com.genuitec.eclipse.server.ui.launching.ServerLaunchConfigurationTab.updateServerConnectors(ServerLaunchConfigurationTab.java:107)
    at com.genuitec.eclipse.server.ui.launching.ServerLaunchConfigurationTab.createControl(ServerLaunchConfigurationTab.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.launchConfigurations.LaunchConfigurationTabGroupViewer.showInstanceTabsFor(LaunchConfigurationTabGroupViewer.java:817)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.launchConfigurations.LaunchConfigurationTabGroupViewer.displayInstanceTabs(LaunchConfigurationTabGroupViewer.java:748)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.launchConfigurations.LaunchConfigurationTabGroupViewer$8.run(LaunchConfigurationTabGroupViewer.java:635)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.launchConfigurations.LaunchConfigurationTabGroupViewer.inputChanged(LaunchConfigurationTabGroupViewer.java:652)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.launchConfigurations.LaunchConfigurationTabGroupViewer.setInput0(LaunchConfigurationTabGroupViewer.java:613)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.launchConfigurations.LaunchConfigurationTabGroupViewer.setInput(LaunchConfigurationTabGroupViewer.java:588)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.launchConfigurations.LaunchConfigurationsDialog.handleLaunchConfigurationSelectionChanged(LaunchConfigurationsDialog.java:960)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.launchConfigurations.LaunchConfigurationsDialog$3.selectionChanged(LaunchConfigurationsDialog.java:573)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$3.run(StructuredViewer.java:876)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.JFaceUtil$1.run(JFaceUtil.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(SafeRunnable.java:178)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.firePostSelectionChanged(StructuredViewer.java:873)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.setSelection(StructuredViewer.java:1708)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.TreeViewer.setSelection(TreeViewer.java:1093)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.Viewer.setSelection(Viewer.java:388)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.launchConfigurations.LaunchConfigurationsDialog.doInitialTreeSelection(LaunchConfigurationsDialog.java:613)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.launchConfigurations.LaunchConfigurationsDialog.initializeContent(LaunchConfigurationsDialog.java:1101)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.launchConfigurations.LaunchConfigurationsDialog.createContents(LaunchConfigurationsDialog.java:446)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.create(Window.java:435)
    at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog.create(Dialog.java:1101)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.launchConfigurations.LaunchConfigurationsDialog.create(LaunchConfigurationsDialog.java:374)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:797)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.launchConfigurations.LaunchConfigurationsDialog.open(LaunchConfigurationsDialog.java:1154)
    at org.eclipse.debug.ui.DebugUITools$2.run(DebugUITools.java:611)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.debug.ui.DebugUITools.openLaunchConfigurationDialogOnGroup(DebugUITools.java:619)
    at org.eclipse.debug.ui.DebugUITools.openLaunchConfigurationDialogOnGroup(DebugUITools.java:552)
    at org.eclipse.debug.ui.actions.OpenLaunchDialogAction.run(OpenLaunchDialogAction.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.Action.runWithEvent(Action.java:519)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:595)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.access$2(ActionContributionItem.java:511)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem$5.handleEvent(ActionContributionItem.java:420)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4454)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1388)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1412)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1397)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.notifyListeners(Widget.java:1182)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem$9.handleEvent(ActionContributionItem.java:1293)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4454)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1388)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:3799)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3409)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1151)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1032)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:636)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:579)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:648)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:603)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1465)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1438)
```

I have no cooking clue of what that problem is connected to, and I cannot recall any major changes that could cause this. So any help will be highly appreciated.

PS Using MyEclipse 2015, Tomcat 7, Ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved**

Removing all breakpoints solved the issue.